# Activate Maven profile based software package installed on deploy server

Tags: maven, maven-2, build, pom.xml

I am using Maven 2.2.1 for building and deploying an application.

I am having a requirement like, if the application is to be deployed on the server it should check whether the server into which the application is to be deployed is installed in the system. If the server is not installed then it should skip all the remaining processes and exit the build process.

Can I do this using profiles?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by activating the profile by the presence of a file. Since your requirement is that the "application is installed on the system" then you can look for a file known to be used by that server software.

For example, if I wanted to activate a profile if WebSphere MQ is installed on a server, I could activate the profile as follows

```
<file>
    <exists>/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar</exists>
</file>
```

Note, this only works if the server software is always installed in the same location.

Reference: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html